# Error registering user in Hyperledger fabric v 2.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, distributed-system, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm trying hyperledger fabric sample(v2.0). My basic network is running fine and i'm able to enroll the admin. however when i tried to register a user, its throwing an error like "Failed to register user "user1": TypeError: gateway.getClient is not a function"

Please find the sample of code below which i'm trying

```
'use strict';

const { Gateway, Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'first-network', 'connection-org1.json');

async function main() {
    try {

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userIdentity = await wallet.get('user1');
        if (userIdentity) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" already exists in the wallet');
            return;
        }

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
        const adminIdentity = await wallet.get('admin');
        if (!adminIdentity) {
            console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the enrollAdmin.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();

        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: true } });

        // Get the CA client object from the gateway for interacting with the CA.
        const client = gateway.getClient();
        const ca = client.getCertificateAuthority();
        const adminUser = await client.getUserContext('admin', false);

        // Register the user, enroll the user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
        const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: 'user1', role: 'client' }, adminUser);
        const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret });
        const x509Identity = {
            credentials: {
                certificate: enrollment.certificate,
                privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
            },
            mspId: 'Org1MSP',
            type: 'X.509',
        };
        await wallet.put('user1', x509Identity);
        console.log('Successfully registered and enrolled admin user "user1" and imported it into the wallet');

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to register user "user1": ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

Note: I'm able to invoke and query the fabcar samples through cli in container and its working fine. when i tried to achieve the same through SDK its throwing an error " Failed to register user "user1": TypeError: gateway.getClient is not a function ". Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone the new copy of registerUser.js file from their offical repository. They have made some modifications to that file in repository. So just take the new copy of the registerUser.js file from their offical repository.